# How to check if a certain value exist in an array which holds objects as its elements. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The first one is when we have an array holds regular elements like strings and I know how to use Includes on it.

But how about arrays holding objects as their element?
How can I check if there is a certain value in those objects?

```js
const arr = ['this', 'is', 'a test'];

console.log(arr.includes('this'));

const arr2 = [
  { id: '123', name: 'Alex' },
  { id: '345', name: 'Dan' },
  { id: '33', name: 'Joe' },
];
```

Comment: Use '.filter()'

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @OnchoMeshkov Why that combination (especially `.map()`)?

Comment: What is the use-case? What is the input? What property (a specific one, any) should be checked? What is the expected output? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `some` function.

```js
const arr2 = [
  { id: '123', name: 'Alex' },
  { id: '345', name: 'Dan' },
  { id: '33', name: 'Joe' },
];

console.log(arr2.some(item => item.name==="this" ))
```

The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a returned array of values that match = >

```
 const filtered = arr2.filter((item)=>item.name == 'value')
```

if you want bool(true||false) =>

```
 const filtered = arr2.filter((item)=>item.name == 'value').length > 0
```

or using some as mentioned above.